# Minimum spanning tree with HashMap java

Tags: java, hashmap, minimum-spanning-tree

Given the output of ascending of edges weight from HashMap "mMap"

```
v6_v5 : 3
v5_v4 : 4
v4_v6 : 5
v5_v3 : 5
v4_v2 : 6
v1_v2 : 6
v5_v1 : 7
v2_v5 : 8
v1_v4 : 9
```

using:

```
private Map<String, Integer> mMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

public void addKeysAndValue(String from, int value) {    
            mMap.put(from, value);
}

for (int i = 0; i < list_from.size() - 1; i++) {
    if (list_dest.get(i + 1).equals(list_from.get(i))) {
        addKeysAndValue(list_from.get(i) + "_" + list_dest.get(i), w_arc.get(i));
    }
}

sorted_map.putAll(mMap);    
Iterator iter = sorted_map.entrySet().iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {

            Map.Entry me = (Map.Entry) iter.next();    
            System.out.println(me.getKey() + " : " + me.getValue());    
}
```

Now I need to find the list of form "mMap" with no loop from ascending of edges weight above as a minimum spanning tree.

Result:

```
v6_v5 : 3
v5_v4 : 4
v5_v3 : 5
v4_v2 : 6
v1_v2 : 6
```

I really appreciate for your help!